# Java Spark Dataset can select but cannot groupBy, filter or aggregate

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to do some rollup with my data using Java, by using Dataset/DataFrame of Java Spark-SQL. However, it throws an error:

```
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task serialization failed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
    at org.apache.spark.util.io.ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.toChunkedByteBuffer(ChunkedByteBufferOutputStream.scala:118)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$.blockifyObject(TorrentBroadcast.scala:295)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1489)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:1163)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1071)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:1014)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2069)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2061)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2050)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
```

My code is like this:

```
Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.createDataFrame(rdd, MyPojo.class); // where rdd has type JavaRDD<MyPojo>
dataset.collectAsList();
```

Why is it throwing this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add [the necessary code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to reproduce the issue? I would _guess_ that there is a problem mit `MyPojo`.